# why is my Collectionview cell.image is gone and messed up?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

so In my collection view cell I have text and image: This is my code in CollectionViewLayout.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let content = HomeCollectionViewController.posts[indexPath.item].content {
        let spaceForPostContentLabel = NSString(string: content).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 120), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)], context: nil)

        if HomeCollectionViewController.posts[indexPath.item].imageURL != nil {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: spaceForPostContentLabel.height + postImageViewOriginHeight + 168.0)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: spaceForPostContentLabel.height + 152.5)
        }
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 408.5)
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, when it first loaded. But when I scrolled down and scrolled up again, everything is messed up, image is gone and there is a huge blank space where the image should have been existed. Does this have to do with dequeReusableIdentifier?

> Note: This error only happen for the first cell, other cell that has image works fine

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening due to how dequeue works. Even if you have 100 cells, there is a limit for cells loaded at the same time, so after this limit, you start reusing old cells as you scroll.

I already faced the same problem sometimes mainly when using images and the best approach that I found, was to use a cache to the images.

Below I'm posting an example using [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) to create the cache (but you can use the cache that you prefer, even the builtin cache provided by Swift's library.

```
import AlamofireImage

let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var imageUrlString: String?

    func loadImageFromURL(_ urlString: String){

            imageUrlString = urlString

            let url = URL(string: urlString)

            image = nil

            if let imageFromCache = imageCache.image(withIdentifier: urlString) {
                self.image = imageFromCache
                return
            }

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

                    if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                        self.image = imageToCache
                    }

                    imageCache.add(imageToCache!, withIdentifier: urlString)
                })

            }).resume()
    }

}
```

Basically I'm creating a subclass of UIImageView and adding the image URL as the key to the image that I'm going to keep in the cache. Everytime that I try to load the image from the internet, I check if the image isn't already in the cache, if it is, I set the image to the image in the cache, if not, I load it from the internet asynchronously.